# Li тег с разными рядами (строками)

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

У меня есть несколько элементов `li`, но я хочу следовать формату следующих `li` для каждой строки (с выравниванием по центру):

```
3
4
3
3
3 и т.д.
```

Я ранее пытался настраивать это во флексбоксе, но не мог понять, как это сделать.
Поэтому я использовал `display: inline-block`.

```css
.meet-team li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.meet-team li:nth-of-type(4),
.meet-team li:nth-of-type(9) {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<ul class="meet-team">
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
</ul>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Li tag with different rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57461928/7394871) от участника  [@Brad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11135642/brad).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/57461928/7394871

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете попробовать flexbox и просто использовать другую гибкую основу - `flex-basis: 25%;` (или ширину) для второй строки:

```css
ul {
 display:flex;
 flex-wrap:wrap;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

.meet-team li {
  list-style-type: none;
  flex-basis: 33%;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align:center;
}

.meet-team li:nth-of-type(4),
.meet-team li:nth-of-type(5),
.meet-team li:nth-of-type(6),
.meet-team li:nth-of-type(7) {
  flex-basis: 25%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="meet-team">
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
  <li>Stuff</li>
</ul>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57462047/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>